# Concat results in a single string returning null value in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, concatenation

In my stored procedure, I concatenate my results into a single string like:

```
Problem1|Problem2|Problem3
```

When I try to store in a variable `@display`, it returns null. When I run the query without storing it to a variable, it returns results. Not sure why its returning null?

```
declare @display nvarchar(500)

select 
@display =  @display + gp2.ProblemDesc  + '|' 
from (SELECT gp.GrantProblemID, gp.ProblemDesc, gps.GrantProblemStatus, row_number() over (partition by gp.grantproblemid order by p.periodid desc) ranking from MergedProgressReport.dbo.[PeriodAgencyGrantProblems] pagp 
inner join MergedProgressReport.dbo.PeriodAgencyGrants pag on pag.PeriodAgencyGrantsID = pagp.PeriodAgencyGrantID and pag.GrantNumber =  '2011UMWX0001'
inner join MergedProgressReport.dbo.periodagencyinfo pai on pag.PeriodAgencyInfoID = pai.PeriodAgencyInfoID  inner join MergedProgressReport.dbo.Periods p on p.PeriodID = pai.PeriodID  
inner join MergedProgressReport.dbo.GrantProblemStatus gps on pagp.GrantProblemStatusID = gps.GrantProblemStatusID inner join MergedProgressReport.dbo.GrantProblems gp on pagp.GrantProblemID = gp.GrantProblemID and gp.GrantProblemAreaID = 7) xx
right join MergedProgressReport.dbo.GrantProblems gp2 on xx.GrantProblemID = gp2.GrantProblemID and xx.ranking = 1 where gp2.GrantProblemAreaID = 7

Select @display
```

Comment: Could it be because you've got two resultsets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Probably you need to initialize the variable.

```
declare @display nvarchar(500)
set @display = ''
```

In short you are missing the `set` statement before you write your query after declaring a variable.

Comment: That worked, but would I need to do when its passed thru a proc?

Comment: Ex:  Exec MyExproc(@SQl nvarchar(3000), @display nvarchar(200) OUTPUT)

Comment: Well seems like @display is your Stored Procedure parameter and not a variable.